# Gravity Theory Question

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, gravity, astrophysics, geomagnetism

Three Questions:

Is the Modern Five Dimension Theory of gravity an adaptation of Einstein's relativity theory?

If so, can it allow us to accurately predict the movement, speed and direction of distant galaxies as they expand outward?

Finally, playing devil's advocate can you think of any test or experiment that might work to detect an electromagnetic correlation to gravity?    (Without the obvious reasons for disagreeing it is possible)

Comment: What is "*the Modern Five Dimension Theory of gravity*"? (I guess its not KK, right?)

Comment: There are many theories on gravity, some of them involving a fifth dimension.  The Kaluza-Klein Theory is the forerunner of the String Theory which includes a fifth dimension.  A lot of us believe a fifth dimension is necessary for a base understanding of the wealth of other theories in quantum mechanics.  Here is an interesting paper I read recently on why physics needs a 5th dimension.  https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1412/1412.6136.pdfBut no, I'm not specifically talking about the KK model.